# TelephonyManager throws Null Pointer Exception in MainActivity

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, telephonymanager, imei

I want to declare `TelephonyManager` in `MainActivity` not `OnCreate`. In `OnCreate` there is no problem but when I use in `MainActivity` it gives a null pointer exception.
Structure of my code is needed to declare `TelephonyManager` in `MainActivity`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().TELEPHONY_SERVICE);//Error line here.
    String imei = mngr.getDeviceId();

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//My jobs
}
}
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: add this `onCreate` section

Comment: Because `getApplicationContext()` return null if it used  at class level

Comment: I should not add in onCrate. Because I should give imei number in MainActivity

Comment: You have to put mngr in onCreate method

Answer (score 2):

Copy this line into your `onCreate` method:

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

You are in a class that extends `Activity` (`Activity` extends `Context`), so you can call `Context`'s methods directly from your class.